# Is there a method to open Apple Wallet application from web page in the iOS

Tags: passbook, wallet, passkit

If I want to open Telegram I use

```
<a href="appName://">Launch App</a>
```

or

```
<a href="https://t.me">Launch Telegram</a>
```

Is there a method to open Apple Wallet application?

Answer (score 3):

Sure, the undocumented URI scheme is `shoebox://`. So this will work:
`<a href="shoebox://">Launch Apple Wallet</a>`